# Spring parse property as String instead of another Property

Tags: java, spring, properties, properties-file

I have an existing property file which I need to use. There, I have to define a new property which looks like - ${testText1}.${testText2}

I do not want these properties to be edited i.e. when I actually fetch these values, I want ${testText1}.${testText2} instead of replaced values.

So my propery file will look like - 
`someProperty=${testText1}.${testText2}`

Now, when i fetch this:

> @Value("${someProperty}")
>
> private String myValue;

myValue should actually contain the string - `${testText1}.${testText2}` and not the replaced values.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways:

1.Define a new configuration class :

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class SomePropertyConfig {

    //name of the property from application.properties
    private String someProperty;

    public String getSomeProperty() {
        return someProperty;
    }

    public void setSomeProperty(String someProperty) {
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
    }
}
```

After that you can autowire this bean

```
@Autowired
 private SomePropertyConfig somePropertyConfig;
```

In this way, the target property will be injected in the configuration

2. If you don't mind changing the application.properties file, you can use spring expression language.

**application.properties**

```
 someProperty= #{'$'}{testText1}.#{'$'}{testText2}
```

Comment: It is generally better to provide a bit of explanation as to why the code addresses/solves the particular question.

Comment: Updated the solution with a short description.

Comment: I have updated the question with an example. I do not want spring to replace the values

Comment: `#{'$'}{testText1}.#{'$'}{testText2}` worked for me, thanks @AdinaFometescu

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working in my case - I end up getting the same string `#{'$'}{testText1}.#{'$'}{testText2}`

Comment: Could you please paste your maven dependencies as well? Maybe you don't have the dependency  "spring-expression". In my case it is provided by "spring-boot-starter-web"